# Value not preserved on thread Named Data Slot

Tags: c#, .net, thread-local-storage

This is pretty simple.  We have code like this:

```
var slot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("myslot");
Thread.SetData(slot, value);
```

The current code exits the thread.  Eventually the thread is re-allocated for more work.  We expect (according to doc and many assertions in SO) that the value will still be there in the slot.   And yet, at least sometimes, it isn't.   It comes up null. The ManagedThreadId is the same as the one we set the value for, but the value has gone null.

We do call some opaque third-party assemblies, but I don't think that there's any way that other code could clear that slot without knowing its name.

Any thoughts on how this could go happen?  Could it be that .net destroys the thread, and later creates another one with the same id?  Does a thread live for the duration of the app domain?

Comment: New thread, new slot. If the thread exists, the local storage is gone. I think you need to rethink your design.

Comment: sure, leppie,  new thread, new slot.  But it's not a new thread, it's the same thread, reused from the pool.  Or is it?  Now I've found http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/development/logging/managed-thread-ids-unique-ids-that-arent-unique, same problem.  I guess threads from the pool don't live forever, and thread id's can be reused.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? It looks like you're doing some pretty weird stuff. Also, you probably don't want to use named slots anyway, there's better options available.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that threads are not forever.  A thread returned to the pool might be reused, or might be discarded.  Take care when leaving something in TLS on a thread, if you don't code a destructor you could have a resource leak.

Here's a post that describes the same issue: http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/development/logging/managed-thread-ids-unique-ids-that-arent-unique

Answer (score 0):

Threadpool threads *do not belong to you*. You're not supposed to rely on their context at all, and that includes stuff like `ThreadStatic` data and `LocalDataStoreSlot`. There's so many things the runtime can do with threadpool threads that will break your code, it's not even funny. This gets even crazier when you start using `await`, for example (the same method can easily execute on multiple different threads, some from the thread pool, some not...).

As an implementation detail (nothing you should rely on), the .NET runtime manages the thread pool to be as big as required. On a properly asynchronous application, this means it will only have about 1-2x the amount of CPU cores. However, if those threads become tied up, it will start creating new ones to accomodate the queued work items (unless, of course, the pool threads are actually saturating the CPU - new threads will not help in that case). When the peak load is done, it will similarly start releasing the threads.

`ManagedThreadId` is not unique over the scope of the `AppDomain` over its life-time - it is only unique in any given moment. You shouldn't rely on it being unique, especially when dealing with threadpool threads. The ID will stay the same for a given thread over it's lifetime (even if the underlying system thread changes - assuming of course the managed thread is actually implemented on top of a system thread) - when you're working with threadpool threads, though, you are not working with actual threads - you're just posting work items on the thread-pool.